# DocuSign - Audit history for Textbox or radio button

Tags: docusignapi

I am able to add Text box and Radio button and other types of control on the document in C# client and also able to fetch the values of these form fields.

But I could not find any API in Rest API documentation or Nuget package about fetching audit data for these form fields.

For example, I am interested to know when text in Textbox was changed or when Radio button selection was done, etc.

Is there any way to get these audit data for form fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presently you cannot obtain the complete audit history for the fields using the docusign API's.

However you can see if a field has been changed by passing the **show_changes=true** parameter to the [getEnvelopeDocuments](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/get/) API.

```
GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/{documentId}?show_changes=true
```

> **show_changes**  When set to true, any changed fields for the returned PDF are highlighted in yellow and optional signatures or initials outlined in red.